# Эмуляция <canvas> в Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Я собираюсь сделать простую игрушку-пазл.

На странице сайта игрок выбирает фото. После этого фото разрезается на квадраты и квадраты перемешиваются. Игрок, щелкая по квадратам, перемещает их на исходные места. Для начала я определился, что буду делать всю отрисовку на canvas.

Возник такой вопрос: как быть с IE, который не поддерживает `<canvas>`? Есть ли что-то, что позволяет и в IE уже сейчас эмулировать его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, смотрите в сторону:

[ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)

Но зачем делать на canvas не понимаю, хотя дело Ваше.

Comment: спасибо, принято :) делаю на canvas с прицелом на будущее, когда его будут поддерживать все

Comment: Просто Ваша задача решается простым js, без canvas и дополнительных фреймворков.